# How do I convert CALLBACK routines to js-ctypes?

Tags: javascript, winapi, jsctypes

I'm working on using ReadFileEx from WINAPI in js-ctypes. I need to setup a callback for LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFileEx(
  _In_     HANDLE                          hFile,
  _In_opt_ LPCVOID                         lpBuffer,
  _In_     DWORD                           nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  _Inout_  LPOVERLAPPED                    lpOverlapped,
  _In_     LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine
);

VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
  _In_    DWORD        dwErrorCode,
  _In_    DWORD        dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
  _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);

typedef VOID (WINAPI *LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)(
    _In_    DWORD        dwErrorCode,
    _In_    DWORD        dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
    _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

My ReadFileEx declaration currently looks like this

```
const readFileEx = kernel32.declare(
  "ReadFileEx",
  ctypes.winapi_abi,
  ctypes.int32_t,       // BOOL
  ctypes.voidptr_t,     // _In_      HANDLE                          hFile,
  ctypes.char.array(),  // _Out_opt_ LPVOID                          lpBuffer,
  ctypes.uint32_t,      // _In_      DWORD                           nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  ctypes.voidptr_t,     // _Inout_   LPOVERLAPPED                    lpOverlapped,
  ctypes.voidptr_t      // _In_      LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine
);
```

**Update.** deleted...

**Update 2.** This seems to work, but the callback is not triggered until Firefox is closed, then it gets called (with the right number of nNumberOfBytesToWrite). Currently not using ChromeWorker.

```
const s_offset = new ctypes.StructType("s_offset",
  [ {"Offset":        ctypes.uint32_t},
    {"OffsetHigh":    ctypes.uint32_t} ]);

const s_overlapped = new ctypes.StructType("s_overlapped",
  [ {"Internal":      ctypes.uint64_t.ptr},
    {"InternalHigh":  ctypes.uint64_t.ptr},
    {"Pointer":       s_offset.ptr},          //  union { struct { DWORD Offset; DWORD OffsetHigh; }; PVOID Pointer; };
    {"hEvent":        ctypes.voidptr_t} ]);

//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks
var OverlappedCompletionRoutine = ctypes.FunctionType(
  ctypes.default_abi,
  ctypes.void_t,           // returns VOID
  [ ctypes.uint32_t,       // _In_    DWORD        dwErrorCode,
    ctypes.uint32_t,       // _In_    DWORD        dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
    s_overlapped.ptr ]     // _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
const readFileEx = kernel32.declare(
  "ReadFileEx",
  ctypes.winapi_abi,
  ctypes.int32_t,       // BOOL
  ctypes.voidptr_t,     // _In_      HANDLE                          hFile,
  ctypes.char.array(),  // _Out_opt_ LPVOID                          lpBuffer,
  ctypes.uint32_t,      // _In_      DWORD                           nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  s_overlapped.ptr,     // _Inout_   LPOVERLAPPED                    lpOverlapped,
  OverlappedCompletionRoutine.ptr      // _In_      LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine
);
```

Elsewhere

```
this.overlapped = new s_overlapped;
this.cReadCallback = OverlappedCompletionRoutine.ptr(this.readCallback);
```

and

```
  readCallback: function(errorCodes, numberOfBytesTransfered, pOverlapped) {
    console.log("readCallback:")
    console.log("  errorCodes " + errorCodes);
    console.log("  numberOfBytesTransfered " + numberOfBytesTransfered);
    console.log("  pOverlapped " + pOverlapped);

    // get the data etc.

    return undefined;
  },
```

finally

```
readFileEx(this.pipeHandle, pBuffer, MAXLEN, this.overlapped.address(), this.cReadCallback);
```

Comment: I am super busy with some work, but this overlap stuff is something I would really love to see working, I need to add it to my ostypes module. I will work on this soon. :)

Comment: I have the callback working now, but it doesn't callback (non-ChromeWorker) until Firefox is closed, then magically the callback happens, it is so odd - I have it in a jpm in index.js

Comment: are you and i the only ones working on this stuff?

Comment: I sent up an update on my original post

Comment: There are a lot of people that use ctypes. I review many addons that use ctypes. They aren't so public with their work as you and I are though.